# How to send confirmation email via PHP and Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, email

I am working on a project with a simple PHP form with Ajax. The form sends email successfully but in AJAX messages it displays an error message that I have set: `'Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent`.
' could it be a server problem?

Also I want to send user a thank you (form submit confirmation) email after they submit the form on my website.

HTML Code:

```
  <form id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="mailer.php">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" required name="name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="email" name="email" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

PHP mailer.php Code:

```
// Only process POST reqeusts.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
            $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

    // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
    if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
        exit;
    }

    // Set the recipient email address.
    // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
    $recipient = "receiveremail@somewhere.com";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "New contact from $name";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email.
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
    } else {
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }

} else {
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}

?>
```

AJAX Code:

```
$(function() {
    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#ajax-contact');

// Get the messages div.
var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

// Set up an event listener for the contact form.
$(form).submit(function(event) {
    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    event.preventDefault();

    // Serialize the form data.
    var formData = $(form).serialize();
    // Submit the form using AJAX.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData
    })

    .done(function(response) {
// Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
$(formMessages).removeClass('error');
$(formMessages).addClass('success');

// Set the message text.
$(formMessages).text(response);

// Clear the form.
$('#name').val('');
$('#email').val('');
$('#message').val('');
})

.fail(function(data) {
// Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
$(formMessages).removeClass('success');
$(formMessages).addClass('error');

// Set the message text.
if (data.responseText !== '') {
    $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
} else {
    $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
}
});
      });
});
```

Comment: Run the mail file without ajax first and see if you are getting any error.

Comment: I ran the file after removing the ajax it worked, i didn't get any error but browers redirected to the mailer.php and it was blank page.

Comment: add error_reporting(E_ALL) in `mailer.php` ans check what error you are getting.

Comment: Didn't get any error and form submitted

Comment: Yes i received the email

Comment: try with ajax now. and in console check what all values are getting posted.

Comment: POST http://www.website.com/demo/mailer.php 500 (Internal Server Error)send @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5m.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5(anonymous function) @ app.js:18m.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4r.handle @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4
jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5 XHR finished loading: POST "http://www.website.com/demo/mailer.php". Still i got the email

Comment: every time u get this error??

Comment: just for a moment, change this `data: formData` to `data: {name: "sample",email:"your emal",message:"hi how are you"}`

Comment: yes, but i still got the email i don't know how

Comment: Tried again, no error and email processed successfully

Comment: is it working without any errors??

Comment: Yes it is working after submitting the form it process and redirects to the mailer.php page

Answer (score 0):

just change this line and check once. even i had the same issue, i solved like this,

```
data: formData
```

to

```
data: {"postvalues":formData},
```

or

```
data: formData to data: {name: "sample",email:"your emal",message:"hi how are you"}
```

If you are using first one, make necessary changes in `mailer.php`. Like this

```
$post = $_POST['postvalues'];
$name = $post['name'];
$email = $post['email'];
$message = $post['message'];
```

If you follow second method, you cant `serialize()` form, and no need to change anything in `mailer.php`.

To send email to user who filled the form, use this

```
if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
    // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
    http_response_code(200);
    echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
    mail($email, "Contact Us", "Thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you soon", $email_headers)
}
```

Comment: How to send a thank you email to the user who has submitted the form?

Comment: use your file `mailer.php`, add code to send to the user who has filled the form.

Comment: Tried with the first option still same result, on form message it gives an error but email processed successfully

Comment: If you provide the required code that will be helpful

Comment: try with second method once.

Comment: Second gives Server Error 500

Comment: The first one, is this a server problem that Ajax not showing success message but processing the email successfully?

Comment: Error on this: data: formData to data: {name: "sample",email:"your emal",message:"hi how are you"}

Comment: Also please mention the code to send thank you email to the user

Comment: at last add comma `,`

Comment: Yes, its the same error with the last comma as well `,`

Comment: Can we try sending thank you email back to the user?

Comment: for whom you are sending email now??

Comment: I would like to send a thank you email to the user who submit the form.

Comment: after you send mail for admin, next add that code. you will have email id of the user who submitted the form, just add `Thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you soon`. and send the email.

Comment: This is where i am getting more confused, which could i should add and where here i need your help please

Comment: you have if condition to check if the mail has went or not, write this code inside that `if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {` write inside this `if()`

Comment: shoudl i write echo 'Thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you soon'; ?

Comment: no, `$message = "Thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you soon'`  and send the message to user.

Comment: sorry man, can you please please please provide me the complete code

Comment: inside if() after echo "";

Comment: add this line `mail($email, "Contact Us, "Thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you soon", $email_headers)`. Then email will go to user who has filled the form.

Comment: This is the new if statement and still not thank you email after submitting the form, i am really getting blank at this stage.
`if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
            $message = "Thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you soon";
        } else {
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }`

Comment: One email is coming in my inbox the other i want to send is to the user who submitted the form.

Comment: @AlrickI have added the code to send email to user who fills the form. please have a check.